# Log Processing Regex for User-Agent Strings

Tags: regex

I'm working on a log processor using regex and I'm having some issues parsing the UserAgent strings since the usual delimiter is a comma (,).

Here's an sample line:
UserName: abc, UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36, Client: Chrome

I'm trying to achieve something that matches the following:
([^:]+):\s(\w+)\,\s([^:]+):\s(Not equals to \,\s\Client in a sequence)\,\sClient:\s(\w+)

How can I achieve "Not equals to \,\s\Client in a sequence" so as to capture the whole user agent string. The user agent strings will come in all formats so I figured that would be the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you want to do.  Give a few lines and then show the expected output.

Comment: I think you just need `(.*?)` - see https://regex101.com/r/PgaZu4/1

Answer (score 0):

Look at what your string looks like:

```
UserName: abc, UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36, Client: Chrome
|-- 1 --| |2|  |-- 3  --| |-------------------------------------------- 4 -------------------------------------------------------|          |-- 5--|
```

The group you need to match is right before the `, Client:` substring. So, you do not even need a complex construct here (e.g. a ["tempered greedy token"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)), just `(.*?)` will do (as it will match any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns).

Your regex can be modified as

```
([^:]+):\s*(\w+),\s*([^:]+):\s*(.*?),\s*Client:\s*(\w+)
                               ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PgaZu4/1)

Note I removed unnecessary escapes (as `:` and `,` are not special regex metacharacters when they are not part of special constructs) and `\s` is better quantified with `*` - 0 or more occurrences.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, this works great. I'm not very familar with the ? operator. But it looks like when used this way, it automatically matches anything in between.

If this is the case, this would work the same way too wont it?
([^:]+):\s*(\w+),\s*([^:]+):\s*(.*),\s*Client:\s*(\w+)

Comment: @Jckx: Yes, it does match anything in between 2 strings, from the leftmost occurrence of the starting delimiter and up to the leftmost occurrence of the end delimiter. It might work the same as `.*` with your inputs, but `.*` matches up to the rightmost occurrence of the end delimiter.

Comment: If you have other examples, please add them to the question to see what problem you have with `.*?`.